# Should a cursor passed onto another function be closed separately (android/java)?

Tags: java, android, cursor

if say I have a cursor in method A and I pass it to method B, should the cursor in B be separately closed?

Comment: It's just one cursor, even if there are two variables that refer to it.

Comment: so if a cursor is closed in B(), it will be inaccessible in A() after A() calls B()?

Comment: Passing cursor to another method B() would be mostly for accessing its values so you can do but preferably always close the cursor in A() so there is no confusion on whether its closed or open in another place. Technically you can do what you asked for but I wouldn't recommend it to avoid confusion and possible exceptions (my two cents).

Comment: @AjayNarayanan Probably.  Don't do it.  Unless method `B` is called `closeCursor` or something similar, it's not the job of `B` to close the cursor.